# Is it mandatory to use "END TRANSACTION" in sqlite

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, transactions, bulkinsert

In my ios app i am inserting a bulk of data into sqlite using for loop, since insertion was very slow i used

```
 sqlite3_exec(dbh, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
```

after using the above statement insertion became very fast,,  now after adding

`sqlite3_exec(dbh, "END TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);` insertion has become slow again,,

when i used only `sqlite3_exec(dbh, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);` insertion was faster,,when i added `sqlite3_exec(dbh, "END TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);`  insertion has become slower,,my question is,,is it mandatory to use "END TRANSACTION" after using "BEGIN TRANSACTION"  ? can i use only  `sqlite3_exec(dbh, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);`  since insertion is faster with only Begin statement

folowing is my code

```
BOOL success = TRUE;
    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;

    const char *strStyleInsertQuery = "insert or replace into tbl (id,hole_number,par,distance,delete_flag,course_id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    NSUInteger intCount = [arrHoles count];
    sqlite3_exec(dbh, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < intCount; i++)
    {
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbh,strStyleInsertQuery, -1, &addStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            if([[arrHoles objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"handicap"] == nil || [[[arrHoles objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"handicap"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
                sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [@"" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            else
                sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 7, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[[arrHoles objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"handicap"] intValue]] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        {
            success = FALSE;
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(dbh));
        }
        //Reset the add statement.
        sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_exec(dbh, "END TRANSACTION", 0, 0, 0);   //IS THIS MANDATORY?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use neither BEGIN nor END, the database will use an automatic transaction for each statement, which is slow.

When you use both BEGIN and END, all the changes done in the transaction will be written to disk and synchronized with the END.

When you use BEGIN but not END, the changes done in the transaction will not be written to disk.
This is certainly faster than with END, but has a negative effect on the correctness of the data in your database.